# U1 Music Streaming: Is it possible to have album cover art for OGG files?

Tags: ubuntu-one, music

Just started trying out the U1 music streaming service and so far very pleased. The one issue I have that could be a deal-breaker when it comes time to pay up is that half of my collection is OGG Vorbis and I cannot find a way to show album art for OGG files.

I already tried adding a cover.jpg to the folder and embedding the image via easyTAG (works for MP3 but not OGG). Does anybody have a solution besides transcoding them all to MP3? Will this likely be supported in future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to Vorbis not having an official way of embedding album art, we don't currently support it.
There are a few different implementations which we may support in the future, but for the time being only mp3's will display album art, I'm sorry.

Comment: After a little research, I can see the problem. Some older programs (like easyTAG that I used) embed in the comments tag using field named COVERART but the recommendation is to use METADATA_BLOCK_PICTURE (which gstreamer doesn't pick up, and therefore nautilus previews don't work, only for COVERART)... however, it would be nice (and I think simple) to support the use of a cover.jpg or other filename.